# What's an automorphism of a function?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, p-adic-number-theory, automorphism-group

I have as a theorem that the automorphism group of a function is homomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.  While it is fairly clear to me what this means im my specific case, I'm unclear what it means **in general**.

**Question:**

What are the automorphisms of a function?

---

The case in particular is as follows:

Let $\Bbb Z_2$ denote the space of $2$-adic integers. Let $f:\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2$ be given by $f(x)=(x-1)/2$ if $x$ is odd and $f(x)=x/2$ if $x$ is even.  Then the automorphisms of this function are homomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

This much is obvious to me:  The automorphism $\phi:x\mapsto -1-x$ exchanges ones and zeroes, therefore there's a symmetry of the function $f$ which exchanges ones for zeroes in the number's binary representation.  Therefore it exchanges the $(x-1)/2$ for the $x/2$ option in the function $f$.  This "automorphism" will also be a homeomorphism and an isometry on $\Bbb Z_2$ and therefore it will **topologically conjugate** $f$ to itself.  Moreover, it is a symmetry of the *functional graph* of $f$.  But it's not the only symmetry of that graph.  The functional graph of $f$ is the infinite non-rooted binary forest, and it would appear to have many symmetries such as picking any tree within it, and exchanging left for right in that tree alone, or below some point in any tree.  None of these, of course, would be homeomorphisms.

I can suggest that the author's intended meaning is that there is only one homeomorphism on $\Bbb Z_2$ which topologically conjugates $f$ to itself.  Is that a standard meaning of an "automorphism of a function"?  Is it standard in the sense of a function on a topological space?  Or is there another definition of automorphism of a function, for which I don't need to invoke the homeomorphism property?

Comment: I don't understand.  What is the definition of an "automorphism of a function"?  And I don't understand your example.  $\mathbb Z_2$ means the integers $\pmod 2$, right?  (you don't mean the $2-$adic integers or anything do you?  But if it is just the integers $\pmod 2$ then any function is specified by $2$ values, $f(0),f(1)$.  What choices did you have in mind?

Comment: Given a function $F:A\to B$, do you mean something like a bijection $\sigma:  A\to A$ which leaves $F$ unchanged?  That is to say, $F\circ \sigma = F$?

Comment: On reflection, I guess you probably do mean the $2-$adic integers.  But why start with such a complicated example?  If you just mean to look at symmetries of the domain under which the function is invariant, it's up to you what properties of the domain you want that symmetry to preserve.  My "bijection" preserves nothing beyond basic set theoretic properties.  Of course you could insist that the symmetry be continuous, or an isometry, or an automorphism of the domain, or all manner of thing.

Comment: @lulu given I use the terminology $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ within the question (and applied the tag p-adic number theory), I hoped it would be clear I wasn't abusing the notation $\Bbb Z_2$ by which I mean the $2$-adic integers. Moreover the question states the functional graph of $f$ is the entire infinite, binary non-rooted forest, which would be absurd in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @lulu the reason for the example is that is the example for which I'm trying to parse the author's precise meaning.

Comment: But it's going to be hard for us to guess what some author had in mind.  Surely they provide a formal definition, no?  With the $2-$adic integers you have group, topological, and valuation structures which you may, or may not wish to preserve.  If for some reason the author doesn't bother providing a definition, perhaps the proof of the Theorem in question reveals the definition.

Comment: @lulu this is the paper: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-3x-%2B-1-Conjugacy-Map-Bernstein-Lagarias/56dfdf65e1d03de836f6cf5c92b5c5876abe8145  but the term was used as if it had a standard accepted meaning. Tentatively I think they mean what I put - i.e. the only homeomorphism which topologically conjugates $f$ onto itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is indeed correct. And it is also confirmed, by the way, by the papers that are cited in the [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/6975BB4A8C46CF6842217043AAF9EC13/S0008414X0004606Xa.pdf/div-class-title-the-3-span-class-italic-x-span-1-conjugacy-map-div.pdf) that you mentioned.

Here is a more general perspective, using [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory).

To every category $\mathcal{C}$ we can associate a new category $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$. Objects are morphisms $f : A \to B$, and a morphism from $f : A \to B$ to $g : A' \to B'$ is a commutative diagram.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> B \\
@V{h}VV @VV{h'}V \\
A' @>>{g}> B'
\end{CD}$$
An automorphism of $f : A \to B$ is then a pair of automorphisms $\alpha \in \mathrm{Aut}(A)$, $\beta \in \mathrm{Aut}(B)$ such that $\beta \circ f = f \circ \alpha$.

If you only look at endomorphisms, you can also take a different definition: We have a category $\mathrm{End}(\mathcal{C})$ that consists of endomorphisms $f : A \to A$, and a morphism $f : A \to A$ to $g : B \to B$ consists of a single morphism $h : A \to B$ with $h \circ f = g \circ h$.

It follows that (in this category) an automorphism of $f : A \to A$ is just an automorphism $\alpha \in \mathrm{Aut}(A)$ with
$$\alpha \circ f = f \circ \alpha,$$
or equivalently
$$f = \alpha^{-1} \circ f \circ \alpha.$$

In the paper that you mentioned, $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{Top}$ is the category of topological spaces and $A$ is the space of $2$-adic integers.

Comment: Thank-you for this.  I'm useless at category theory and I haven't fully parsed your answer yet but should your $h'$ not be an $h$? (or have its arrow reversed?)

Comment: I guess where I interpreted "automorphism of a function", if I had instead interpreted it as "automorphism of an automorphism", i.e. I interpreted the "auto" as meaning "preserving the automorphism property", I would have understood them correctly, right?.